# Django paginator appears to not go through all rows

Tags: django, pagination

I'm trying to backfill a table to add data to a new column.  The table is rather large so I'm trying to do it in chunks, so it doesn't lock the whole table, and so I can restart the process in case it fails partway and is half done.  I'm using the Paginator class to break it in chunks.

The problem is, after this script finishes running, it looks like it's only processed a fraction of the table.  There's many, many more rows left if I query for rows where the new column is empty.  It seems like it goes through at most 1/2 the table on each run, sometimes substantially less.  Running multiple iterations eventually processes the entire table, but I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my code.

The backend DB is postgres

```
queryset = models.MyModel.objects.filter(new_column=None).exclude(
           unrelated_field=None).values_list('id', flat=True)
pages = Paginator(queryset, batchsize)

for page in pages.page_range:
    ids = pages.page(page).object_list:
    models.MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=ids).update(
        new_column='Some data')

print("Done.")
```

Comment: The code inside your for loop is a bit odd. You are iterating over `object_list` (i.e., going through one object at a time) but then doing a filter/update operation (as though you were updating many products at a go). If you want to update each object individually then there's no need for the new queryset (in your code that object is `ids`) - you already have the object in `object_list` - you can just edit it and save it.

Comment: You're right, I was trying to clean it up the actual code a bit to make it more readable, but I made some mistakes.  Let me try to fix it up.  I'm mostly trying to iterate one page at a time.